# Tag trends by week

Tags: discussion, tags, data-dump, graphs

Using the data dump, I've put together some [tag trend graphs](http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/stack_overflow/tagtrend.html) that show the rate of tagged questions over time. Below are some samples, there are many more on the linked page. I can update the page with requests for specific tag groups if you're interested.

**Update:** There's a new [interactive tag trend graph](http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/stack_overflow/tags/) page where you can select any set of tags to compare. Also, the graphs are improved and have a labeled X axis.

### Popular Languages (c#, java, php, javascript, c++, python)

[image]

### Distributed Source Control (git, mercurial, bazaar)

[image]

### Javascript Libraries (jquery, prototype, mootools)

[image]

### Meta (subjective, not-programming-related, polls, belongs-on-serverfault, stackoverflow)

[image]

Comment: Id love to see these for Superuser

Comment: With a Superuser data dump, it would be possible. :)

Comment: Guess Jeff should get to work then ^^

Comment: nice, you could add maven-2 to "Build Systems"

Comment: @Rich Seller: good addition, thanks.

Comment: oh no, thank you, really like the graphs

Comment: I don't see `autotools` under the Build Systems. Or does no one ask questions about autotools on StackOverflow?

Comment: @Chris, not a huge amount. 44 total, 3 last 30 days, 1 last 7 days: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=autotools&sort=stats&pagesize=50

Comment: Awesome work! How often do you update them? Is it possible to add actual week to them?

Comment: It would be nice to have the x-axis labeled.

Comment: @Pablo and @Andrew: The latest revision at http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/tags/ labels the x-axis.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill: Great graph! Maybe you could make it RESTful, by adding the tags on the graph in the querystring, so you can send the diagram with a link. Could be useful.

Comment: @Sanoj: Click the [link] button.

Comment: @Greg: The trend site doesn't seem to work anymore :( I liked it!

Comment: @Jonas: I fixed the links. Also, now you can query the tag stats for [any SE site](http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/).

Comment: @GregHewgill: Some of the graphs on the site seem to be broken. When I try to access them directly, I get an error page from the Google Charts API saying the URLs are too long.

Comment: Can you please add the swift-language tag to the interactive data presentation?

Comment: @KendallHelmstetterGelner: I haven't updated the graph data for a while (been busy). Next time I update it, new tags like "swift-language" will automatically appear.

Comment: @GregHewgill Any ideas to make it with newer data or (even better!) live?

Comment: @PiotrMigdal I built something similar with live data here http://sotagtrends.com

Answer (score 4):

While % is useful, I'd *personally* be more interested in the growth of individual tags. Perhaps normalising the current counts (i.e. so they all end at 1 or 100 or something), so we can see which tags are linear / sub-linear / super-linear / stagnant / etc.

My point is: a sudden spike (in either direction) by itself doesn't mean much - it could just be that there was a rush on people learning "ook". The overall trend of the % is interesting, though. Thanks for the data.

Comment: +1 It's very difficult to visually integrate.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who might be interested I put together an interactive tag comparison. You can put in up to 4 tags and compare them over a date range and granularity. [Check it out here](http://www.ioncannon.net/projects/sostats/tag_compare.html).

Comment: Great idea, but it seems that the page doesn't work anymore. I'm getting an endless "Running query" and no charts.

Answer (score 2):

This tool gives you **actual values, individual percentage growth, 6 month history, and live queries** so the data is always up to date:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/90306

Answer (score 1):

I would love to see the graphs show cumulative number of posts, rather than activity.  Activity is valuable, but it's hard to visually integrate to see how big the total bodies of information are.  This kind of comparison can give very valuable clues about the health of the community around a project you'r considering using.  I don't care how much better you think mootools is than jquery -- look at that graph above and the sensible choice is obvious.

Also, I made this a feature request here:
[Graph trends for activity within tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105693/graph-trends-for-activity-within-tags)

Comment: There could be a lot of reasons why a particular tag has less volume than another.  I can think of at least two, the documentation for the project is better than average, the people who use that particular technology do not know about or share questions and answers via the SO platform.  It is difficult to know how many folks don't use the site!

Answer (score 0):

I like these.  Here are some more ideas if you've got time:

- iphone/blackberry/android/palm
- windows/unix/linux/mac
- ie/firefox/chrome/safari/opera

**Edit** oops, my eyes jumped over the text to the pretty graphs.  Looks like you've got all three of these (or something close) on [the linked page](http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/tagtrend.html).

Comment: I added 'unix', as well as 'blackberry' and 'palm-os'. Everything is dwarfed by 'iphone' in the mobile space.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I LOVE these graphs.

I'd like to see graphs of activity for....

- r <-- especially this, with the "flash-r-mob" thing that happened a few months back
- f#

Also I'd like to see a plot of homework, I'm wondering if that spikes around Sept 1 and Jan 15. :-)

edit: i r dumb. i need to look at linx.

Comment: You're quite right about `homework`! Check this out: http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/tags/?homework

Comment: Awesome! I has a win!