# How can I access history of a SO tag?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, graphs, popularity

I'm interested in graphs showing the number of questions on given SO tag over time.

Are these data available?

Answer (score 3):

Greg Hewgill has some nice graphs:

[Stack Overflow stats graphs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65/stack-overflow-stats-graphs)
[Tag trends by week](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23554/tag-trends-by-week)

And in fact the whole [graphs] tag is pretty solid reading:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphs

Comment: For future readers, I'm keeping the linked pages (on my server) up to date with each monthly data dump. The latest data is not necessarily reflected in the graphs in the questions above.

Comment: @GregHewgill: can you post a link to these updated plots? The ones on the post are two years old and I'd love to see how things have chhanged for some tags since then.

Comment: @user189035: I haven't updated the graphs in a while, I've been busy and the size of the data dump exceeded the capability of my computer. Maybe I'll update them sometime.